# Is there a way to get only the top 50 friends from the friendslist using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Can someone advice if there is a possibility of geting just the top 50 friends from Facebook using Graph API. I currently get all the friends from Facebook, which kind of slows down the requests and take a while for it process. Could someone advice on this.

Comment: is `?limit=50` not working? What are you doing, exactly?

Comment: I guess it would depend on how you define top 50 friends? Did you mean the first 50 friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the limit and offset querystring parameters like this: `me/friends?limit=50&offset=0`

Test it [here on the Facebook graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friends?limit=50&offset=0).